# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when using json

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this code to generate columns and am trying to use json to put names into the boxes. However when I try to run the code it gives me the error in the title.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     console.log("registered stories ready!");

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
      $("#stories").append(
        "<div class='col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>\
          <a href='C:/Users/Vlad/Desktop/Coursera-Assignments-master/docs/Sample Stream.html'>\
            <img src='img/placeholder.jpg' alt='placeholder' class='images'> <br>\
            <p class='who-is-reading' id='firstname'>Firstname is reading</p>\
            <p class='book-title'>Story Title</p>\
          </a>\
        </div>");
  }
                              });
</script>

<script>
  var myObj, x;
  myObj = {
    "age":30,
    "name":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
  };
  x = myObj.name[0];
  document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You reference the element before it is added to the page...Second issue, you have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how it is referenced before it is loaded. Doesn't html load sequentially?

Comment: document ready is asynchronous and waits for the page to load. The other script is after it and runs before. Simple console.log() will show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your are appending the HTML on Document.Ready event but you are accessing the DOM before the HTML gets appended. Here is an example on how you can fix the issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("registered stories ready!");

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { 
            $("#stories").append(
            "<div class='col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>\
                <a href='C:/Users/Vlad/Desktop/Coursera-Assignments-master/docs/Sample Stream.html'>\
                <img src='img/placeholder.jpg' alt='placeholder' class='images'> <br>\
                <p class='who-is-reading' id='firstname-" + i + "'>Firstname is reading</p>\
                <p class='book-title'>Story Title</p>\
                </a>\
            </div>");
        }

        var myObj, x;
        myObj = {
            "age":30,
            "name":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
        };
        x = myObj.name[0];
        document.getElementById("firstname-1").innerHTML = x;
    });
</script>
```

Notice how `document.getElementById("firstname-1").innerHTML` is also inside Document.Ready block.. Also make sure your Ids are unqiue